# Exceptions: why does adding parenthesis change anything?

Tags: ruby, exception

There are a few things I'd like to understand in how Ruby treats inline Error handlers

**Case 1**

This is a common use case

```
def foo
  raise Error
end

bar = foo rescue 1
# => 1
bar
# => 1
```

It works as expected. The expression `foo rescue 1` returns `1` and it is correctly assigned to `bar`.

**Case 2**

Ruby allows descructuring arrays, so this behavior seems odd.

```
baz = 'a'
baz, bar = foo rescue [1, 2]
# => [1, 2]
baz
# => 'a'
bar 
# => nil
```

The expression returns the array `[1, 2]` but doesn't deconstruct or assign it. It completely skips the assignment altogether.

**Case 3**

When you wrap the the error in parenthesis, however, the deconstruction works.

```
baz, bar = (foo rescue [1, 2])
# => [1, 2]
baz
# => 1
bar
# => 2
```

**Case 4**

Bonus points: Raising the Error and trying to handle it inline also skips assignment

```
baz = raise Error rescue 1
# => 1
baz
# => nil
```

But adding parenthesis makes it work.

**Edit**:

I tested this on Ruby 1.9.3-p392 and Ruby 2.0.0

**Edit 2**:

I added labels to cases

**Edit 3**:

Apparently some folks think this isn't a question, so maybe the title wasn't obvious enough. Here's the question in full text:

Why do these inconsistencies happen, and why does adding parenthesis change anything?

Comment: Be extremely careful using inline `rescue`. It seems very useful until you encounter a syntax error or IO exception, and that `rescue` hides it. It is a loaded and cocked gun aimed at your foot.

Comment: There is [`precedence of single-line rescue and assignment`](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/152260) similar issue earlier. But `Yukihiro Matsumoto` recognized that as a problem and now it has been fixed.So you may raise it as a bug ticket.

Comment: Bug was reported as https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case 2 is the same as this:

```
baz = 'a'
(baz, bar = foo) rescue [1, 2]
```

Since `foo` raises an error, assignment of values to `baz` and `bar` fails, so `baz` remains to be `"a"`, and `bar` remains to be `nil`, a value that was assigned during the parsing stage. Then, the assignment gets rescued, and the return value would be `[1, 2]`.

Your case 4 is the same as this:

```
(baz = raise Error) rescue 1
```

Since the righthand side of the assignment raises an error, assignment to `baz` fails, and `baz` would remain to be `nil`, that was assigned during the parsing stage. Then, the assignment is rescued, and the return value is `1`.

Comment: Why wouldn't `bar = foo rescue 1` be the same as case 4 and be treated as `(bar = foo) rescue 1` ?

Comment: I suppose the associativity strength of modifiers like `rescue`, `if`, `while` etc. is strong when the modifee is a single token.

Comment: So it all boils down to the precedence of flow control vs assignment operators?

Comment: How can a precedence explain why at simple assignment the left side is updated with value of rescue "block" and at multiple assignment does not ?

Comment: Whether it is destructive assignment matters.

Comment: ```(baz = raise Error) rescue 1``` is *not* equivalent to ```baz = raise Error rescue 1``` If you test the latter, baz *gets* updated in contrary and equals to 1. Tried in Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Sorry, my example did not worked. I guess this is a bug in the parser as simple assignment does not suffer this issue.

```
bar, baz = 1,2  # bar == 1, baz == 2
bar = foo rescue [3,4] # bar == [3,4], baz == 2
bar, baz = 1,2  # bar == 1, baz == 2
bar, baz = foo rescue [3,4] # no assignment done:  bar == 1, baz == 2
```

Even precedence of rescue can not explain why the simple assignment is done and multi- does not.